# Grep wildcard in the middle

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

How do I match lines like these with UNIX's `grep`?

```
call($variable, 'tiki-index.php');
call('string123', 'tiki-index.php');
call(13, 'tiki-index.php');
```

I tried

```
user@host:~$ grep -e "smarty->assign(*, 'tiki-index.php');" .
```

but the command matches none of the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `grep -e "smarty->assign(*, 'tiki-index.php');"` would match the following:

```
smarty->assign(, 'tiki-index.php');
smarty->assign((, 'tiki-index.php');
smarty->assign(((, 'tiki-index.php');
...
```

(i.e. `*` is applied to `(`.)

You wanted to specify any character, i.e. `.` and then match `*` instances of it.  Use:

```
grep -e "smarty->assign(.*, 'tiki-index.php');"
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use -R to make the search recursive.
If you don't want the search to be recursive, do the search on * and not .

And you need to change your regex to:

```
"call(.*, 'tiki-index.php');"
```

or, with smarty:

```
"smarty\->assign(.*, 'tiki-index.php');"
```

See documentation about regular expressions for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following file

```
 cat x.txt 
call($variable, 'tiki-index.php');
call('string123', 'tiki-index.php');
call(13, 'tiki-index.php');
call(sdfadf..df.d.foo);
small(12, 'tiki-index.php');
```

my grep returns following, you can make it as specific or general as you want

```
grep -e "call.*\'tiki-index.php\');" x.txt 
call($variable, 'tiki-index.php');
call('string123', 'tiki-index.php');
call(13, 'tiki-index.php');
```